# Druid firehose bottleneck in StringDimensionMergerV9

Tags: java, druid

I'm trying to bulk load data into druid using a local firehose, but I'm losing a lot of time in the class `StringDimensionMergerV9`. It seems to take about a millisecond per row in this phase, which seems way off.

Is there anything I can tune to speed this up?

```
2019-09-25T22:11:45,216 INFO [appenderator_merge_0] org.apache.druid.segment.StringDimensionMergerV9 - Completed dim[date] conversions with cardinality[1] in 5 millis.
2019-09-25T22:11:49,640 INFO [appenderator_merge_0] org.apache.druid.segment.StringDimensionMergerV9 - Completed dim[ric] conversions with cardinality[3,834] in 4,420 millis.
2019-09-25T22:12:41,242 INFO [appenderator_merge_0] org.apache.druid.segment.StringDimensionMergerV9 - Completed dim[value] conversions with cardinality[39,752] in 51,598 millis.
```

Comment: Can you add you ingestion spec to this, and maybe a short description of your data's dimensions/metrics. I have a feeling that the issue is due to wrong/unoptimal dimension spec

Comment: @ArtemVovsia I had a string as one of my dimensions. I couldn't figure out how to get druid to not index it even though I didn't need it indexed. I ended up converting the string to a couple of doubles (easy in my use case), and the ingestion was lightning fast again. Didn't figure out a real fix.